# Technology/way to automatically put two (or more) videos together

Tags: video, editing

I'm working on a project where we want to be able to like fetch multiple video sources, record them and make one video out of it.

Do you know any library or even an online service that could handle this task? At this state of the project, the language that the library is written in does not matter.

Just to be clear: The video fetching part is not the question. It is just about put the recorded videos together.

Thank you all,
Jonas

Comment: Why is this closed as off topic? Where is the right place to ask such a question? Is it not allowed to ask for the right technology or maybe finde someone who has the experience doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper solution for that would be to integrate a video decoding/encoding library like [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [libav](http://libav.org/)
But they are written in c and not easy to handle.

Alternatively you might remote control some video editing program like after effects or an open source alternative, generate project/script files and let them do the work via command line call.

Third idea would be to simply generate apple container MOVs which just reference the source videos. That would be easiest solution, but those container MOVs wont run everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've looked at ffmpeg before and I thought that it is mostly like a video converting engine and not for what I try to accomplish. Have you ever done something like that with one of the above libraries?

Comment: Well, the ffmpeg executable is a conversion tool. But you asked for a library and at the core it is a full fledged programmer api to decode/encode/mux videos. Many video editing software is based on it. On the downside it is not easy to use and not well documented.